# Passing a reference to lambda by reference

Tags: c++, lambda, reference

Is there any difference between `f1` and `f2`?

```
void foo(const std::string& test){

    auto f1 = [&test](){
        std::cout << test << std::endl;
    };

    f1();

    auto f2 = [test](){
        std::cout << test << std::endl;
    };

    f2();
}

int main()
{
    std::string x = "x";
    foo(x);
}
```

It looks like in both cases, the type of the `test` variable inside of the lambda will be `std::string const&`, but is it really the same?

Comment: `It looks like in both cases the type of variable test inside lambda will be std::string const&` Where is the look like part? You can test this with a dummy class that prints something inside of the copy constructor. Short answer: They're not the same.

Comment: `[&test]` does not capture ”a reference to a reference”, it captures a reference to the object that `test` refers to. `[test]` captures the value of the object that `test` refers to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there any difference between f1 and f2?

Yes.

> but is it realy the same?

No. `f2` captures a `std::string const`.

Type deduction of lambda captures works the same as `auto` declarations:

```
[&test](){}              // a reference
[ test](){}              // an object

auto        &var = test; // a reference
auto         var = test; // an object

std::string &var = test; // a reference
std::string  var = test; // an object

template<class T> void foo1(T& var);
template<class T> void foo2(T  var);
foo1(test);              // a reference
foo2(test);              // an object
```

Comment: Nitpick: the constness of the capture _is_ because the captured entity was const. The captured string would still be const, even if the lambda were mutable. See slides 22-25 of [Scott Meyers Type Deduction](https://www.aristeia.com/TalkNotes/C++TypeDeductionandWhyYouCareCppCon2014.pdf): "cv-qualifiers are retained".

Comment: @Oktalist Thanks for pointing that out. I removed the misleading point.

Comment: The type of variable `test` inside lambda **is** `std::string const&` (one can check with `is_reference_v<decltype(test)>`. Nevertheless the variable is captured by copy (i.e. changing it inside the lambda, once the code is modified such that it is not `const`, will not propagate back to the original variable).

Comment: @n.m. I changed wording.